# Javascript remember combobox value

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, combobox

I currently have 3 combo boxes containing values which apply styles to the page using javascript.

All these styles are applied to a cookie and read on body load, however I'd like to also set the combo box's values to match the applied styles.

How do I go about setting a combo box value based on a cookie or applied style?

```html
<select name="sizes" onchange="fontSize(accessibility.sizes.value);"> 
  <option value='-1'>Select</option>
  <option value='10'>Small</option> <option value='12.75'>Medium</option>
  <option value='15.5'>Large</option>
</select>
```

```js
function fontSize(textSize) { 
  var element = document.getElementById('content'); 
  if (element) {
   element.style.fontSize = textSize + 'px'; 
   createCookie("Font Size", textSize, 365);   
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If changing the select is changing the style, first select the relevant value then trigger the onchange. Notice I changed your script to save the selectedIndex and to apply the change after I set the index. Also please notice I pass (this) which the the select object itself and I have added an ID to it. Lastly I put the medium fontsize as the first item in case people want to reset. Please change that to whatever is the default font size

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('sizes');// get the select with ID=sizes
 // the following statement gets the select and sets the index to the cookie content if
 // there IS a cookie, else it sets it to 0
 var idx = getCookie("FontSizeIdx") || 0;
  sel.selectedIndex = parseInt(idx,10); // make sure it is a number
 // now call the function and pass the select to it
  fontSize(sel);
}
function fontSize(sel) { // select object is passed as (this) and ends up here as (sel)
  var textSize = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; // get the value
  var element = document.getElementById('content'); // get the content object
  if(element) { // does it exist?
    element.style.fontSize = textSize + 'px'; // set the font size 
    createCookie("FontSizeIdx", sel.selectedIndex, 365); // save the index
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="sizes" id="sizes" onchange="fontSize(this);"> 
<option value='12.75'>Select (default is medium)</option> 
<option value='10'>Small</option> 
<option value='12.75'>Medium</option> 
<option value='15.5'>Large</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: @Cristian - Please show some code. the selects, cookie and css javascript

Comment: choosing select doesn't change the style, i just need for example if(document.cookie.textSize == '10')
   combobox.setvalue = Small;
sorry for being so clueless about this

Comment: <select name="sizes" onchange="fontSize(accessibility.sizes.value);">
   <option value='-1'>Select</option>
   <option value='10'>Small</option>
   <option value='12.75'>Medium</option>
   <option value='15.5'>Large</option>
</select>

Comment: function fontSize(textSize) {
   var element = document.getElementById('content');
   if(element) {
      element.style.fontSize = textSize + 'px';
      createCookie("Font Size", textSize, 365);
   }
}

Comment: i also have a script which checks the cookie on startup and reapplies the values, in that script i could add to set the combo box value as well? thanks for all your help

Comment: Please see update. Change getCookie to whatever your get cookie is called

Comment: Just need to re-read it about a thousand times to get my head around it :D thanks for all your help, much appreciated!

Comment: i see what you've done, and has completely replaced my existing code :D the problem is that the combo box does not remember its value :(

Comment: it's not online yet, all the styles are applied and work through the combo boxes.
Going to another page keeps all the styles by using the cookie, and checking the cookie onload, however the combo boxes reset back to the first option: 'select', is there any way to set the combo box value to a certain option? perhaps with an if statement using the font size set in the cookie? for example if you choose Medium, and then refresh/switch page the combo box stays on medium?

Comment: it should set the select to the saved index - it does not care what the value is which means it can be used with whatever number of fonts you have - I can change the code to remember the size, but I think you (or I) just have a bug in the code. See the added parseInt. Please load the page into firefox and look in the console for errors and post them if any

Comment: i'm not sure if it's the cleanest method, but I made a solution myself, working perfectly. I just added the onload check cookie to set the value of the combo box depending on what size is in the cookie:
function checkSize() {
   var cookie = readCookie("Font Size");
   textSize = cookie ? cookie : 12.75;

   var element = document.getElementById('sizes');
   if(textSize == 10)
      element.value = "10";
   else if(textSize == 12.75)
      element.value = "12.75";
   else if(textSize == 15.5)
      element.value = "15.5";

   fontSize(textSize);      
}

Comment: That is indeed not cleanest. It should be enough to do element.value=textSize if textSize is sure to contain one of the options